# R: Create new dataframe using levels from 2 factors

Tags: r

Is it possible to create a new dataframe using levels of two factors?

E.g. I have two factors that look like this:

```
table(df$year,df$name)

        BENJAMIN RALPH GEORGE 
2001        0     70       40         
2002       16     91        0           
2003       84      0       33
```

I am trying to create a new dataframe that I can populate with coefficients from model outputs where each year is examined separately and name is a factor in the models for each year

i.e. I would like it to look like this:

```
YEAR NAME  Coefficient
2001 RALPH     <blank>
2001 GEORGE    <blank>
2002 BENJAMIN  <blank>
2002 RALPH     <blank>
2003 BENJAMIN  <blank>
2003 GEAORGE   <blank>
```

Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `duplicated` to keep only unique levels of `year` and `name` column and use `transform` to create `Coefficient` column with `NA` value.

```
cols <- c('year', 'name')
result <- transform(df[!duplicated(df[cols]), cols], Coefficient = NA)
```